# Sort a list by alpha values first, numeric values next

Tags: c#, linq

```
class ListSort
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] partNumbers = new string[] 
        { 
           "India", "US","UK", "Australia","Germany", "1", "7", "9" 
        };
        var result = partNumbers.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();                    
    }
}
```

I tried the above code, and expected the following output:

```
Australia
Germany
India
UK
US
1
7
9
```

**EDIT**:
Numbers should be ordered numerically (1, 7, 9, 70, ...), while the non-numbers should always be ordered lexically, even if there's a number inside ("A3stralia", "Australia", "Germany").

Comment: What about string `"50cent"`? Should it be considered as string or as numeric? Also what if you will have `70` instead of `7`? Should it be last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] partNumbers = new string[] 
  { 
    "India", "US","UK", "Australia","Germany", "1", "7", "9" 
  };

var result = partNumbers.OrderBy(x => char.IsNumber(x.FirstOrDefault())).ThenBy(x => x).ToList().Dump();
```

Note that this will only work if your data is either numeric or text, not if there's a value like "U2S". I can change this to work for those cases too, if you need that, though. Also, the numeric strings are still gettings sorted as strings, so "10" comes before "2".

How would you want the result to be when you add `A3stralia` and `70` to the list?

EDIT: Changed for the new constraints:

```
string[] partNumbers = new string[] 
  { 
      "India", "US","UK", "Australia","Germany", "1", "7", "9", "70", "A3stralia" 
  };

var result = 
    partNumbers
        .Select(x => { int p; bool isNumber = int.TryParse(x, out p);  return new { IsNumber = isNumber, NumericValue = isNumber ? p : int.MinValue, StringValue = x }; })
        .OrderBy(x => x.IsNumber)
        .ThenBy(x => x.NumericValue)
        .ThenBy(x => x.StringValue)
        .Select(x => x.StringValue)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: @user2864740: So? I say so in my answer. We need the OP to confirm the proper sorting for the cases he didn't specify.

Comment: Well if its in the case of A3stralia and 70....A3stralia should be above/below(doesn't matter) of Australia and 70 should be next to 9 i.e., 1,7,9,70

Comment: @user3080252: please don't add such important informations to a comment to some of the answers. Instead (also) edit your question.

Comment: @user3080252: I've updated the answer to give the results you want - text is sorted as text, and numbers are sorted as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't matter that the digit part is ordered lexicographically:

```
var result = partNumbers.OrderBy(s => s.All(Char.IsDigit)).ThenBy(s => s).ToList();
```

This just simply checks whether all characters are digits or not. If you want the digits first use `Enumerable.OrderByDescending` instead.

As commented to one of the answers you want to order the digits numerically, then you need to parse them first:

```
result = partNumbers
  .Select(s => new { s, num = s.TryGetInt() } )
  .GroupBy(x => x.num.HasValue) // two groups: one can be parsed to int the other not 
  .SelectMany (xg =>
  {
      if (xg.Key) // can be parsed to int, then order by int-value
          return xg.OrderBy(x => x.num.Value).Select(x => x.s);
      else       // can not be parsed to int, order by the string
          return xg.OrderBy(x => x.s).Select(x => x.s);
  })
  .ToList();
```

I'm using this extension to parse `strings` to `Nullable<int>` in LINQ queries:

```
public static class NumericExtensions
{   
    public static int? TryGetInt(this string item)
    {
        int i;
        bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
        return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, my tired eyes mixed the post and an answer :-/

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: I didn't see it, edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So far it seems all the responses are roughly the same, but all too complicated. My attempt:

```
string[] partNumbers = { "US", "1", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "70", "9" };
partNumbers.OrderBy(x =>
    { 
        int parseResult; 
        return int.TryParse(x, out parseResult) 
            ? parseResult 
            : null as int?; 
    }) 
    .ThenBy(x => x);
```

Or, with extracted helper method:

```
partNumbers.OrderBy(TryParseNullableInt).ThenBy(x => x);

private static int? TryParseNullableInt(string source)
{
    int parseResult; 
    return int.TryParse(x, out parseResult) 
        ? parseResult 
        : null as int?;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution projects string sequence into anonymous type `{ isNumber, s, value }`, which contain current item from sequence, information whether item is integer number, and possible parse result. Then new sequence if grouped into two groups - one for numbers and one for other strings. Each group is sorted - numbers by numeric comparison, strings alphabetically. And original item is selected from flattened groups:

```
string[] partNumbers = { "US", "1", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "70", "9" };
int value;
var result = partNumbers
    .Select(s => new { isNumber = Int32.TryParse(s, out value), s, value })
    .GroupBy(x => x.isNumber)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Key ? g.OrderBy(x => x.value) : g.OrderBy(x => x.s))
    .Select(x => x.s)
    .ToList();
```

Returns:

```
"Australia",
"Germany",
"UK",
"US",
"1",
"9",
"70"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] partNumbers = new string[] 
                            { 
                                "India", "US","UK", "Australia","Germany", "1", "7", "9" 
                            };

    var result = partNumbers.OrderBy(x =>
                {
                    int i;
                    return int.TryParse(x, out i);
                }).ThenBy(x=>x);
```